# Override service for specific user role

Tags: symfony, sulu

I have 3 services which should override the default services only if the user has a specific role.

Or even better. Inject the current user/security in the new services.
The service then performs the check for the user role and calls the original service.

I tried to inject `security.context` into it. But then `$security->getToken()` returns `null`.

In the controllers it works fine. How can i get the current user in my service? This is what i want to do:

```
class AlwaysVisibleNavigationQueryBuilder extends      NavigationQueryBuilder
{
    public function __construct(\Sulu\Component\Content\Compat\StructureManagerInterface $structureManager, $languageNamespace, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        if (in_array('ROLE_SULU_ADMINISTRATOR', $security->getToken()->getRoles())) {
            // Show unpublished content, too
            $this->published = false;
        }

        parent::__construct($structureManager, $languageNamespace);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the constructor the security context don't have yet the info, you need to call in the method

Comment: Thanks, your hint solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment of creation of the service, the securityContext was not aware of the current user. The Security is filles when the application runs and not on dependency-resolution.

The following Code works.

```
class AlwaysVisibleNavigationQueryBuilder extends NavigationQueryBuilder
{
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(\Sulu\Component\Content\Compat\StructureManagerInterface $structureManager, $languageNamespace, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;

        parent::__construct($structureManager, $languageNamespace);
    }

    public function build($webspaceKey, $locales)
    {
        $roles = $this->security->getToken()->getRoles();

        if (in_array('ROLE_SULU_ADMINISTRATOR', $roles)) {
            // Show unpublished content, too
            $this->published = false;
        }

        return parent::build($webspaceKey, $locales);
    }
}
```

Thanks to Matteo!